# It was Terry who hit on this idea, not me. / It was Terry, not me, who hit on this idea

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-order

> (1) It was Terry who hit on this idea, not me.
>
> (2) It was Terry, not me, who hit on this idea.

Is it possible to rephrase (1) as (2)?

(1) is quoted from a grammar book for Japanese high school students.

Comment: Either is idiomatic and they are perfectly interchangeable, meaning exactly the same thing.

Comment: They're not *always* "perfectly interchangeable". Consider *It was Terry who married my sister, not me* - which with nothing else to go on could be interpreted as implying either *Terry didn't marry me* OR *I didn't marry my sister*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To some extent I agree. But with the relative pronoun present it would be an awkward interpretation that he didn't marry his sister. For that to apply the last two words would need to be "...not I."

Comment: @WS2: Speak for yourself! I only really know ***...not I*** from [*Who Killed Cock Robin?*](https://www.birdspot.co.uk/culture/who-killed-cock-robin) I doubt I've ever in my life been on speaking terms with anyone who would normally say *"Not **I**"* rather than *"Not **me**".*

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've clearly lived a sheltered life! But thinking about it again I hear what you are saying. However my latest thought is that *It was Terry who married my sister, not me* could not possibly mean that Terry failed to marry me. For that to apply surely you would have to remove the "who". It would have to be *Terry married my sister, not me!*

Answer (score 2):

*not me* is an interruption and can be placed at both locations shown in OP's examples; the examples have the same meaning.

Edit

The use of the it-cleft makes it clear that the comparison is between Terry and me.

Consider an example not using the it-cleft:

1a) Terry hit on this idea, not me.

2a) Terry, not me, hit on this idea.

#2a means the same as #2 minus the emphasis **Terry**.

#1a is ambiguous.  It could mean either the same as #1 minus the emphasis or

> Terry did not [hit on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hit-on) me.

with the phrasal verb taking sense 2 definition:

> If someone hits on you, they speak or behave in a way that shows they want to have a sexual relationship with you.

Comment: See my comment under the question. You might want to include something about that in your answer, for completeness. My example might not be the best possible for showing the potential ambiguity, but I think it establishes the *principle*.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers.  I have edited my answer but with a non it-cleft example.

Comment: I'd already upvoted, but that's *such* an improvement I wish I could upvote again!